# Do not allow special characters except the allowed characters javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript code for my password strength indicator:

```
if (password.match(/([!,@,#,$,%])/)
{
    strength += 2
}
```

So what this do is if the password contains one of these allowed characters (!,@,#,$,%), it will add a value to the strength of indicator.

My problem is I also want to decrease the strength of the password indicator once other special characters are present on the password. For example: ^,`,~,<,>

To remove confusion, basically I don't want any other special characters except the ones that is present above (!,@,#,$,%). So I did it hard coded, writing all special characters that I don't want.

I tried using this:

```
if (password.match(/([^,`,~,<,>])/)
{
    strength -= 2
}
```

But I also don't want to include `"`, `'` and `,` but then if I include them on my if condition, it will throw me an error saying syntax error on regular expression. I understand this because i know `"` represents a string which must be closed. Can I do something about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please teach yourself: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions)

Comment: Just remind you, charactors in `[]` of a regex is not comma separated, it does not need any separators, neither.

Comment: don't use comma inside brakets `[!@#$%]` and `[^\`~<>]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to separate your individual characters by commas, nor do you need to wrap the only term in brackets.

This should work:

```
/[`^~<>,"']/
```

note the carat (`^` is not at the front, this has a special meaning when placed at the start of the `[]` block)

Also you should use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) because you only want a boolean if-contains result

```
/[`^~<>,"']/.test(password)
```

Comment: but if I include the `/` inside, it will give me an error eg: `(/[~^()/]/)`

Comment: then just escape it by prefixing with a backslash. eg `/[~^()\/]/`. Do study @Teemu's link

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is escape each of `"`, `'`, and `,` using a `\`. The regex you're looking for is:

```
/([\^\`\~\<\,\>\"\'])/
```

I actually generated that using the [JSVerbalExpressions](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JSVerbalExpressions) library. I highly recommend you check it out! To show you how awesome it is, the code to generate the above regex is:

```
var tester = VerEx()
            .anyOf("^,`'\"~<>");

console.log(tester); // /([\^\`\~\<\,\>\"\'])/
```

Comment: There're no needs to escape any char in character class, excepted `^` in first position and the delimiter of the regex `/`. And eventualy `-` when not in first or last position.

Answer (score 1):

Include these special characters in square brackets without commas and see if it works.

You can try it out here - http://jsfiddle.net/BCn7h/

Eg :

```
if (password.match(/["',]/)
{
    strength -= 2
}
```